# Accessing state value from remember variable versus accessing it directly inside the composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am having trouble accessing the state value with remember and without remember.
I have following composable screen:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AddEditSeriesScreen(
    viewModel: AddEditSeriesViewModel,
    seriesId: Int?
) {
    seriesId?.let {
        viewModel.getSeriesById(it)
    }

    val state by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    var seriesName by remember {
        mutableStateOf(state.seriesBeingEdited?.seriesName ?: "")
    }

    Scaffold {
        Column(...) {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(...)
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
            ) {
                item {
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        value = seriesName,
                        onValueChange = { name ->
                            seriesName = name
                        },
                        label = {
                            Text(text = "Series Name")
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

State setup in viewmodel:

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(AddEditSeriesUiState())
val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

AddEditSeriesUiState class

```
data class AddEditSeriesUiState(
    val isEditModeActive: Boolean = false,
    val seriesBeingEdited: Series? = null,
    ...
)
```

Getting series in viewModel:

```
fun getSeriesById(seriesId: Int) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val series: Series? = repository.getSeriesById(seriesId)
        series?.let {
            _uiState.update { currentState ->
                currentState.copy(
                    isEditModeActive = true,
                    seriesBeingEdited = it
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the challenge I am having is, this setup with remember doesn't work.
If I directly access the seriesName in the OutlinedTextField using state variable, without saving it in remember, it works.
For example if I do this:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    value = state.seriesBeingEdited?.seriesName ?: "",  // WORKS
    value = seriesName,                                 // DOESN'T WORK
    onValueChange {
    
    }
    ....
)
```

this works fine, but I can't update the series name in onValueChange this way.

There may be a very small thing I am missing here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if your `val state by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()` state is being determined by your viewmodel, why use a remember for the series name ? why can't `onValueChange` communicate to your viewmodel to update the state and then you rely on state as your source of truth everywhere ?

Comment: Got it. Thanks!! That's the way I need to go.. YEAH!!!